# Issue while triggering mail using mailx command

Tags: shell, email, unix, mailx

I am trying to trigger mail using mailx

Below is the Command which i am using

```
NOTIFICATION_GROUP=$(cat email.lst)

mailx -s "Success Of the ABC" $NOTIFICATION_GROUP < log_file.txt
```

email.lst contains

```
anc@domain.com
esdfg@domain.com
awsd@domain.com
fcgv@domain.com
```

When i try to trigger a mail i am getting below error and also i am not receiving any mail

```
anc@domain.com
esdfg@domain.com
awsd@domain.com
fcgv@domain.com invalid character '\012'
Send options without primary recipient specified.
Usage: mailx -eiIUdEFntBDNHRVv~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS -c USERS -S OPTION users
```

Could anyone help me out with the above issue. It will be very helpful

Comment: Did you use a Windows text editor to create the file `email.lst`? Show the output of `od -c -tx1 email.lst`  Please don't use comments to answer, [edit] your question instead. Add a line `set -x` to your script or run it with `sh -x yourscript [args if necessary ...]`

Comment: This is out of scope for SO, it should be posted on linux sites.